# Calling activity method to implement view pager fragment from adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter, getview

I have to call this initViewPagerandTabs() method from my activity in my Adapter. This method implements sliding tab layouts.  It works fine when called by another activity or fragment but not from base adapter.

Is there a simple way I can call my method from adapter class. Please help.

Adapter Class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View myview=convertView;

    if (myview == null) {
            Log.d("network frag list"," convertView null ");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_post, null);
        myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Post.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                   }
        });
```

Post.Class

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

         initViewPagerAndTabs();

    }

    public void initViewPagerAndTabs() {
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        PostActivityPagerAdapter adapter = new PostActivityPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        SlidingTabLayout tabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(false);
        tabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.ark_green);
            }
        });


        tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a reference to your activity when you create your adapter (by modify the adapter constructor). Then use that reference to call the methods.

Comment: public NotificationdPostAdapter(Context ctx, List<PostResponse> networkPostList ) {
          this.context = ctx;
  this.mNetworkPostList = new ArrayList<PostResponse>(networkPostList);

 }

Comment: This is my adapter contructor

Comment: If you put `getActivity()` for the `Context` when you create this adapter then you can cast your `context` to the activity and call the function: `((<Your activity>) context).<Your function>`